# tab lines with bulleted paragraph style

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, paragraph

[image]

I am in InDesign and I want to align all the text vertically but am not sure how to do it, it wont let me space or tab because of the bullets.I just want to move the lines under the bulleted line and not affect the whole paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be easy, first you have to apply bullets to the paragraphs you have, you can achieve this from multiple places, for now you can go to the Main Menu and then under Type you can find Bullets and Numbering from there chose Apply Bullets.

This will give you the desire effects using predefined numbers, you can then change those numbers under the Paragraph Palette as show in the image!

Hope this helps.[image]

Comment: oh right negative indenting forgot about that thanks!